# Can't fit all 8 bytes into unsigned long long

Tags: c, hex

I'm trying to fit 16 hex values into an unsigned long long in visual C

```
unsigned long long test = 0x1A2A00DABABA7890;
printf("long long value %X\n", test);
printf("%d", sizeof(test));
```

My output shows it is 8 bytes but only storing the first 4 bytes as
it outputs

```
long long value BABA7890
8
```

Am I misunderstanding how this works? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `printf` format specifier doesn't match your type, which causes undefined behaviour.  Try:

```
printf("long long value %llX\n", test);
```

`%d` is the wrong format for a `sizeof` result too.  You should be using `%zu` there.

Your compiler may warn you if you turn up some warning settings (`clang` does by default, for example):

```
example.c:6:30: warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument
      has type 'unsigned long long' [-Wformat]
    printf("long long value %X\n", test);
                            ~^     ~~~~
                            %llX
example.c:7:14: warning: format specifies type 'int' but the argument has type
      'unsigned long' [-Wformat]
    printf("%d", sizeof(test));
            ~^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~
            %ld
2 warnings generated.
```

Edit:  I notice in your question that you're using Visual C.  `%z` is a C99 feature and might not be supported by your compiler.  In that case you should check the documentation to see the right format to use.

Comment: This is why you should always have compiler warnings on by default.

Answer (score 1):

The correct format specifier for an `unsigned long long` is `llX` (that's ell-ell, not eleven).

From the standard:

> **ll (ell-ell):** Specifies that a following `d`, `i`, `o`, `u`, `x`, or `X` conversion specifier applies to a `long long int` or `unsigned long long int` argument; or that a following `n` conversion specifier applies to a pointer to a `long long int` argument.

Answer (score 1):

It is storing it properly but you are not printing it properly

For an unsigned long long, you need to use %llX

Answer (score -1):

You need to specify the width of the integer. By default, printf will assume it is 32 bits. Use the I64 prefix, like this:

printf("long long value %I64X", test);

This is documented here for Visual C/C++:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/56e442dc(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: I believe I64 is for MSVC only, and not standards compliant.

Comment: @Timothy, OP says he's using Visual C.